# fastest method to get indices of first and last common elements between lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two sorted lists

```
x = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [3,4,5,6]
```

Between these `x` and `y` I would like to return `imin = (6,0)` and `imax = (9,3)`. If these lists do not share any elements, I would like to return `imin = None` and `imax = None`.

A solution is

```
def inds(x,y):
    arr = [(i,j) for i,xx in enumerate(x) for j,yy in enumerate(y) if xx==yy ]
    if arr!=[]: # to obtain proper None output
        imin = (min(i for i,_ in arr), min(j for _,j in arr))
        imax = (max(i for i,_ in arr), max(j for _,j in arr))
    else: 
        imin = None
        imax = None 
    return (imin,imax)
```

This does a lot of unnecessary computation (O(n**2)) and is a bottleneck of one of my programs. Can anyone suggest something faster?

**ADDITIONAL (NON-MINIMAL EXAMPLE) INFO**

If it helps, I actually have a list of objects.

```
objects = [(A1,B1),(A2,B2)]
```

`x` and `y` would be attributes of each element of this objects list like so:

```
x = objects[0][0].attrib
y = objects[0][1].attrib
```

and I actually want to generate

```
[(imin1,imax1),(imin2,imax2)]
```

Which could come, for example, from

```
def attribs(A,B):
    return (A.attrib,B.attrib)

[inds(*attribs(*v)) for v in objects]
```

note: I added a numpy tag just because I'm open to using numpy for this if it's faster.

Comment: Are those two lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: yep, they are always sorted

Comment: How is `iy = (9,3)` ? there are not `9` items in `y` Shouldn't `iy = (0, 3)` Also shouldn't `ix = (6, 9)` not `(6, 0)` ?

Comment: sorry, naming is a little weird. iy is actually the indices of the max elements in x and y respectively. I will edit

Comment: ah ok I'll delete my answer and adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are after

```
c = set(x).intersection(y)  # O(n) time
def get_first(l):
    return next((idx for idx, elm in enumerate(l) if elm in c), None)  # O(n) time
imin = (get_first(x), get_first(y))
imax = (len(x) - get_first(x[::-1]) - 1, len(y) - get_first(y[::-1]) - 1)
```

From here onwards you can do a few tweaks but it will still run `O(n)`

Comment: 106 times speedup on a system size of interest :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.intersect1d` and returning the indices, you can do the following

```
idxes = np.stack(np.intersect1d(x,y, return_indices=True)[1:])
ix = tuple(idxes[:,0])
iy = tuple(idxes[:,-1])

>>> ix
(6, 0)
>>> iy
(9, 3)
```

**Explanation**

`idxes` is a 2d array of the indices where there are intersections between your two arrays:

```
>>> idxes
array([[6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

So you can just take the first and last using

```
ix = tuple(idxes[:,0])
iy = tuple(idxes[:,-1])
```

Comment: Note that this is a very new function in `numpy` and only in versions `1.15.0` and higher

Comment: @sacul my np.intersect1d() doesn't have a return_indices kwarg. Any idea about this? I have `numpy` `1.13.3`

Comment: thanks @AlexanderMcFarlane.  sacul Do you expect this to be O(n)?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it wasn't. Sometimes you can't really be sure with `numpy` though. Best way is to run for array lengths of `10, 100, 1000, 10000` and plot the log gradient

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to check the time complexity of numpy functions, but @AlexanderMcFarlane's solution of plotting should give a good hint

Comment: Tbh I think they might be `nlog(n)` because I saw in the source there is a sort algorithm here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L376

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort the intersection list and use `.index()` to find out the indices.

```
z = list(set(x).intersection(set(y))) # O(n)
z.sort() # O(nlogn)

imin = (x.index(z[0]), y.index(z[0])) # O(n)
imax = (x.index(z[-1]), y.index(z[-1])) # O(n)
```